# Ubuntu 16.04 - Third monitor has mouse but no background or window

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

This is my first post so forgive me in advance if I don't post all the correct information. I'm having trouble getting a third monitor to work on Ubuntu 16.04. I have a Lenovo MT-M10 with an integrated Intel graphics card (DP and VGA outputs).

Initially the system works well with 2 monitors (DP w/DVI adapter & VGA). I wanted a third monitor so I added a Nvidia GeForce G72 card and a monitor w/ DVI and VGA. I changed the video settings in the bios to default to the integrated card and set it for dual cards/monitors.

When I boot up, all 3 monitors come on but I can only see my desktop on the two connected to the integrated card. I can, however, move my mouse to all 3 of them but cannot place a window on the third.

Also, if I set the bios to use the Nvidia, Ubuntu has an issue installing the drivers. It will complete the install with errors and allows me to open the Nvidia configuration but there aren't any options in it except for setting up a profile.

I did run xrandr and it shows all monitors and lspci does show both cards. Unfortunately, that is about the extent of my diagnostic skills. I will re-install the drivers for the Nvidia card and post a screenshot of the errors along with the output of the xrandr command when I get back to my office.

Thanks